# Trying to trigger a 500 error in AWS AppSync

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

New to AWS AppSync (and GraphQL in general). We setup logging from AppSync -> CloudWatch -> Kinesis -> Splunk and we are trying to trigger/induce an error that would produce a 500 from Appsync and hopefully gives us some logs that we can write a Splunk alert on.

Does anybody know how to trigger a 500 error on AppSync? Currently our backing datasource is Elastic, messing with the templates just returns a 200 with the errors array populated, so that doesn't help produce an error log.

Comment: I have quite the same problem, I want to setup a CloudWatch alarm on GraphQL internal resolver errors... but 5xx and 4xx are not relevant because the internal resolver error is "catch" by the GraphQL implementation to a "clean" error. Does anyone know how to setup proper error logs (available to CloudWatch alarm)

Comment: @YvesM. I am facing the same issue. Did you find a solution please?

Answer (score 0):

AWS AppSync is a managed GraphQL service, and it honors the GraphQL specification completely. Per GraphQL Specification, a response may contain both a partial response as well as encountered errors in the case that a field error occurred on a field which was replaced with null, [as described here](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/draft/#sec-Errors).

In your case, if you are trying to induce an error either from the DataSource, or from the Mapping Template, it will lead to a null resolution of this field, with the "errors" field in the response populated.

If you have (AppSync -> CloudWatch -> Kinesis -> Splunk) setup and are trying to ingest some data into Splunk for testing, you can try the following as a way to test it out:

- Enable Logs from the settings page on your AppSync console. You should either select "ERROR" or "ALL" as a field-level option.
- Within your Mapping Template, on any of your resolvers, you can either introduce a syntactical error, or make your DataSource raise an exception.
- AppSync will then log the resolved Request/Response Mapping templates for each field, where the JSON payload will contain `{ "fieldInError": true }` for the fields that are resolved in error.
- You can use this as a filter pattern to ingest into Splunk, via Kinesis stream.

Answer (score 0):

You accomplish this with a combination of Cloudwatch Custom Metrics and Log Group Filters.

An example configuration in terraform is:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter" "appsync_errors" {
  name = "Some Name"

  pattern        = "{ $.fieldInError IS TRUE }"
  log_group_name = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.your.name

  metric_transformation {
    name          = "your_metric_name"
    namespace     = "your_namespace"
    value         = "1"
    default_value = "0"
    unit          = "Count"
  }
}
```

You can either create an alert on this custom metric, or stream the custom metric somewhere else.